# Nodejs how to convert an ejs file to a pdf file without changing the look of the page

Tags: html, node.js, express, html-pdf

hello i wrote an ejs file and i try to convert it to pdf via `nodejs` but the probleme is that the pdf file did not look like the html page i tryed this conversion online and i found good result this is my method

```
router.get("/uknow", (req, res) => {

 //console.log(data[1].test);

  //console.log(posts);
  ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'views', 'resultat.ejs'), {}, function(err, str) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);

    // str now contains your rendered html
    pdf.create(str).toFile("report.pdf", function(err, data) {
      if (err) return res.send(err);

      res.send('Ok');
      });    
    });
  });
```

and this is my ejs look
[image]
and i want the pdf file to have the same look but it looks like this
[image]
i need some help and thank you

and that's my ejs code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Bootstrap 4 Grid Layouts for Large Devices</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  div + div {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
  svg{
    height:30px;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .gridd{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:

    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer'

    ;
  grid-gap: 10px;


  padding: 10px;
}

.spacer {
   
   margin: 10px 170px;
}
hr {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        border: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
      .div{
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}

      
      h2{
        text-align: center;
      }
      body{
      
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left:200px;

      }
      .griddd{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:

    'left right'

    ;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.gridd-item {
  display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;align-items: center;
  
}

.gridd-item span {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.gridd-item svg{
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  
  background: rgb(237,209,94);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237,209,94,1) 0%, rgba(196,134,0,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237,209,94,1) 0%, rgba(196,134,0,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237,209,94,1) 0%, rgba(196,134,0,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#edd15e",endColorstr="#c48600",GradientType=1);
  
}
.gridd-item svg path {
  filter: invert(1);
}

.right-part {
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.right-part .gridd-item {
  margin-right: 20px;
}           
</style>
</head>
<body >
    <h2 class="text-center my-3"> posts[0].imei.model </h2>
    <h5 class="text-center my-3"> posts[0].imei.name </h5>
    <h3 class="text-center my-3">Resultat des tests</h3>
    <h5 class="text-center my-3">Date:</h5>
    <hr>
    <div class="gridd">
        
<svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
          <span style="grid-area: main;">Ecran</span>
          <br>
          <span style="grid-area:footer;">health</span>
       <span>
      
 <svg  height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M7 7.07L8.43 8.5c.91-.91 2.18-1.48 3.57-1.48s2.66.57 3.57 1.48L17 7.07C15.72 5.79 13.95 5 12 5s-3.72.79-5 2.07zM12 1C8.98 1 6.24 2.23 4.25 4.21l1.41 1.41C7.28 4 9.53 3 12 3s4.72 1 6.34 2.62l1.41-1.41C17.76 2.23 15.02 1 12 1zm2.86 9.01L9.14 10C8.51 10 8 10.51 8 11.14v9.71c0 .63.51 1.14 1.14 1.14h5.71c.63 0 1.14-.51 1.14-1.14v-9.71c.01-.63-.5-1.13-1.13-1.13zM15 20H9v-8h6v8z"/></svg>

  <svg  style="position: relative;" data-name="Layer 102" viewBox="0 0 100 125" x="0px" y="0px"><path d="M62.12,4H13.38A5.76,5.76,0,0,0,7.63,9.75v80.5A5.76,5.76,0,0,0,13.38,96H62.12a5.76,5.76,0,0,0,5.75-5.75V84.77L71.7,88.6a3.57,3.57,0,0,0,5.06,0L91.32,74a3.56,3.56,0,0,0,0-5.05l-8.49-8.5A3.59,3.59,0,0,0,78.49,60c-1.45-1.94-5-7-5.64-10.07a15.94,15.94,0,0,0-2.48-6.14,28.41,28.41,0,0,0-2.5-3.15V9.75A5.76,5.76,0,0,0,62.12,4Zm3.75,86.25A3.76,3.76,0,0,1,62.12,94H13.38a3.75,3.75,0,0,1-3.75-3.75V9.75A3.75,3.75,0,0,1,13.38,6H62.12a3.76,3.76,0,0,1,3.75,3.75v29A7.82,7.82,0,0,0,62.13,37a4.91,4.91,0,0,0-2,.16V12.84a2.34,2.34,0,0,0-2.34-2.34H17.66a2.35,2.35,0,0,0-2.35,2.34V78a2.35,2.35,0,0,0,2.35,2.34H57.84A2.34,2.34,0,0,0,60.18,78V75.77l2.13.87a3.55,3.55,0,0,0,.9,3.47l2.66,2.66Zm-27.5-59,9.86,9.86A8.7,8.7,0,0,0,46,42.73a8.47,8.47,0,0,0-1.73,2.38,2.53,2.53,0,0,0-.11,2.35,6.6,6.6,0,0,0-1.74,1.26A5.55,5.55,0,0,0,41,51a2.65,2.65,0,0,0,.22,2.25,5,5,0,0,0-1.46,1,4.07,4.07,0,0,0-1.21,2.32,3.27,3.27,0,0,0,1,2.8l9.54,9.54a29.33,29.33,0,0,0,7.41,5.38l1.63.67v3a.34.34,0,0,1-.34.34H17.66a.35.35,0,0,1-.35-.34V12.84a.35.35,0,0,1,.35-.34H57.84a.34.34,0,0,1,.34.34V37.43L45.63,24.88c-2.18-2.18-4.16-2-5.15-1.76a5,5,0,0,0-3.34,3.63A4.58,4.58,0,0,0,38.37,31.22ZM79,62.08l.17-.17a1.54,1.54,0,0,1,1.11-.46,1.58,1.58,0,0,1,1.12.46l8.49,8.49a1.59,1.59,0,0,1,0,2.23L75.35,87.19a1.61,1.61,0,0,1-2.23,0l-5.25-5.25-1-1-1-1L64.63,78.7a1.57,1.57,0,0,1,0-2.23l1.24-1.24,1-1,1-1ZM68.73,44.88a14.06,14.06,0,0,1,2.16,5.38c.68,3.57,4.63,9.07,6.09,11L67.87,70.4l-1,1-.76.76-.24-.1-3.25-1.33-2.44-1-.07,0c-.32-.16-.62-.35-.93-.52s-.67-.37-1-.57a27,27,0,0,1-4.9-3.89L51.46,62.9l-4-4A1,1,0,0,0,46,60.29l5.84,5.85a29.73,29.73,0,0,0,6.32,4.77c.33.18.66.38,1,.56l.09,0,.91.37,4.39,1.8-1.21,1.22-3.18-1.3-1-.41-1-.41-.79-.33a27.28,27.28,0,0,1-6.84-5L41,58a1.34,1.34,0,0,1-.47-1.14,2.11,2.11,0,0,1,.65-1.16,2.43,2.43,0,0,1,1.49-.77.24.24,0,0,1,.15,0,1,1,0,0,0,1.42,0,1,1,0,0,0,.29-.7,1,1,0,0,0-.29-.71L43,52.26c-.3-.3-.09-.84.15-1.24a4.08,4.08,0,0,1,2.51-2,1,1,0,0,0,1.41,0,1,1,0,0,0,.29-.71,1,1,0,0,0-.29-.71l0,0L46,46.53c-.06-.25.33-1.23,1.48-2.39a4.77,4.77,0,0,1,2.33-1.51,1,1,0,1,0,1.42-1.42h0L39.76,29.79a2.61,2.61,0,0,1-.67-2.56A3,3,0,0,1,41,25c1-.28,2.1.16,3.2,1.25l14,14,1,1,1,1,2.2,2.19A1,1,0,1,0,63.79,43l-3.61-3.61-.09-.09.09,0A2.76,2.76,0,0,1,61.89,39a7.48,7.48,0,0,1,4,2.41c.33.33.66.68,1,1.07s.66.79,1,1.23S68.44,44.46,68.73,44.88Z"/>
         </svg>
         </span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="gridd">
      <svg  style="grid-area:menu;"class="bi bi-volume-up" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.717 3.55A.5.5 0 0 1 7 4v8a.5.5 0 0 1-.812.39L3.825 10.5H1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 1 10V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2.325l2.363-1.89a.5.5 0 0 1 .529-.06zM6 5.04L4.312 6.39A.5.5 0 0 1 4 6.5H2v3h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .312.11L6 10.96V5.04z"/>
        <path d="M11.536 14.01A8.473 8.473 0 0 0 14.026 8a8.473 8.473 0 0 0-2.49-6.01l-.708.707A7.476 7.476 0 0 1 13.025 8c0 2.071-.84 3.946-2.197 5.303l.708.707z"/>
        <path d="M10.121 12.596A6.48 6.48 0 0 0 12.025 8a6.48 6.48 0 0 0-1.904-4.596l-.707.707A5.483 5.483 0 0 1 11.025 8a5.483 5.483 0 0 1-1.61 3.89l.706.706z"/>
        <path d="M8.707 11.182A4.486 4.486 0 0 0 10.025 8a4.486 4.486 0 0 0-1.318-3.182L8 5.525A3.489 3.489 0 0 1 9.025 8 3.49 3.49 0 0 1 8 10.475l.707.707z"/>
      </svg>
          <span  style="grid-area:main;">Son</span>
          <br>
          <span  style="grid-area:footer;">health</span>
        <span>  
        <span  class="rounded-circle">      <svg id="inner-circle" style="grid-area:menu;"viewBox="0 0 24 24"class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em" ><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M18 7V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H8c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v3H5v6l3 6v3h8v-3l3-6V7h-1zM8 4h8v3h-2V5h-1v2h-2V5h-1v2H8V4z"/></svg>
        </span>
        <span class="dot">      <svg id="inner-circle" style="grid-area:menu;"viewBox="0 0 24 24"class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em" ><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M18 7V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H8c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v3H5v6l3 6v3h8v-3l3-6V7h-1zM8 4h8v3h-2V5h-1v2h-2V5h-1v2H8V4z"/></svg>
        </span>
        <span class="dot"><svg id="inner-circle" style="grid-area:menu;"viewBox="0 0 24 24"class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em" ><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M18 7V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H8c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v3H5v6l3 6v3h8v-3l3-6V7h-1zM8 4h8v3h-2V5h-1v2h-2V5h-1v2H8V4z"/></svg>

      </span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="gridd">
      <svg  style="grid-area:menu;"viewBox="0 0 24 24"class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em" ><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M18 7V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H8c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v3H5v6l3 6v3h8v-3l3-6V7h-1zM8 4h8v3h-2V5h-1v2h-2V5h-1v2H8V4z"/></svg>
          <span  style="grid-area:main;">Materiel</span>
          <br>
          <span  style="grid-area:footer;">health</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="gridd">
      <svg style="grid-area:menu;" class="bi bi-wifi" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.858 11.858A1.991 1.991 0 0 1 8 11.5c.425 0 .818.132 1.142.358L8 13l-1.142-1.142z"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.731 12.024l.269.269.269-.269a1.507 1.507 0 0 0-.538 0zm-1.159-.576A2.49 2.49 0 0 1 8 11c.53 0 1.023.165 1.428.448a.5.5 0 0 1 .068.763l-1.142 1.143a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L6.504 12.21a.5.5 0 0 1 .354-.853v.5l-.286-.41zM8 9.5a4.478 4.478 0 0 0-2.7.9.5.5 0 0 1-.6-.8c.919-.69 2.062-1.1 3.3-1.1s2.381.41 3.3 1.1a.5.5 0 0 1-.6.8A4.478 4.478 0 0 0 8 9.5zm0-3c-1.833 0-3.51.657-4.814 1.748a.5.5 0 0 1-.642-.766A8.468 8.468 0 0 1 8 5.5c2.076 0 3.98.745 5.456 1.982a.5.5 0 1 1-.642.766A7.468 7.468 0 0 0 8 6.5z"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5c-2.657 0-5.082.986-6.932 2.613a.5.5 0 1 1-.66-.75A11.458 11.458 0 0 1 8 2.5c2.91 0 5.567 1.081 7.592 2.862a.5.5 0 1 1-.66.751A10.458 10.458 0 0 0 8 3.5z"/>
      </svg>
          <span  style="grid-area:main;">Connectivite</span>
          <br>
          <span  style="grid-area:footer;">health</span>
          
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    <div class="gridd">
      <svg  style="grid-area:menu;"class="bi bi-camera" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M9 5C7.343 5 5 6.343 5 8a4 4 0 0 1 4-4v1z"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.333 3h-2.015A5.97 5.97 0 0 0 9 2a5.972 5.972 0 0 0-3.318 1H1.667C.747 3 0 3.746 0 4.667v6.666C0 12.253.746 13 1.667 13h4.015c.95.632 2.091 1 3.318 1a5.973 5.973 0 0 0 3.318-1h2.015c.92 0 1.667-.746 1.667-1.667V4.667C16 3.747 15.254 3 14.333 3zM1.5 5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zM9 13A5 5 0 1 0 9 3a5 5 0 0 0 0 10z"/>
        <path d="M2 3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1z"/>
      </svg>
      <div class="griddd">
        <div class="gridd-item" style="grid-area: left;">
        <p >Bonjour</p>
                  <span>Ecran</span>
              </div>


          <div class="griddd">
            <div class="gridd-item" style="grid-area: left;">
            <svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
                      <span>Ecran</span>
                  </div>
               
              
              <div class="right-part" style="grid-area: right;">
              <div class="gridd-item">
            <svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
                      <span>Ecran</span>
                  </div>
              
              <div class="gridd-item">
            <svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
                      <span>Ecran</span>
                  </div>
              
              <div class="gridd-item">
            <svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
                      <span>Ecran</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
               </div>
          
        
    </div>
    <hr>
    
        
  
    
    

    
   
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the template itself. The code seems to be working fine - are you able to post it?

Comment: the ejs template ok i will post it

Comment: i addes the code with some new details

Comment: So just looked at it and i just tried to do a command print on my mac and it seems to be shifting to the right hand side. The problem is the HTML syntax and the CSS itself. You need to fix the core HTML & CSS to get this working. Also take a look at how your using css `grids`.

Comment: some part of css are bootstrap and some are from the net can you give me some helps